# How can I show a loading-skeleton / shimmer effect in ReactJS for an Owl-carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, npm, loader

Any NPM library, or utilizing CSS transition ideas are welcome.

I have already tried out the following NPM libraries:

1. [react-loading-skeleton](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loading-skeleton)
2. [react-skeleton-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-skeleton-loader)

But if you have a way to make it work, please do help!

I am not able to change the size of their respective loaders in order to look like an owl-carousels

These are the two owl-carousels, I wanna show loading-skeleton for.

[image: owl-carousel]

Comment: What are your ideas if you want to build it by yourself? Any idea, how this could be achieved?

Comment: @wiesson it would be awesome if I could utilize a 3rd party library, will make my workflow easier

Comment: Though if I had to do it myself, I would probably do it using CSS and showing and hiding it during the fetch request.

Comment: I would go the same way, create the loading effect first, then think about when you have to show the loader and then implement it - done. No package required, less loading time for the user :)

Comment: Thanks, man I have implemented the loading logic. Now I ll work on the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass in some fake data to the carousels?

```
const apiData = fetch(...)

<Carousel data={apiData.length || [{title: "...", image: "some_dummy_image.jpg"}]}
```